# Provided a misleading example. What now?

Tags: discussion

I asked this [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263516/how-to-calculate-confidence-intervals-for-ratios) about how to analyze the results of my experiments. In order to illustrate my problem I made the mistake to give another example that apparently made several people think my experiment actually works exactly as my example, which is not the case.

I made an edit and added some more context, but in my opinion the question is now unnecessarily complex to understand and has developed more into a discussion about why my experiment is different from my example.

There are multiple good answers that would be great *if* my experiments would behave like a repeated Bernoulli experiment, but they do not answer my question, because the experiments actually don't behave like that.

So what now? I see several options:

- Cleaning up the question and removing the misleading example. That would however make it difficult to understand the existing answers and comments.
- Just leave it like that. Maybe someone comes along and has a great answer anyway.
- Playing Jeopardy and reformulating the question so that it exactly matches the answers and accept one. Then posting a new similar question without the misleading example, but with more context about my approach.
- Other ideas?

Comment: I don't quite get it. What exactly is misleading about your example? The fact that in your experiment (unlike your example), the 1000 events inside one experiment are not independent?

Comment: @amoeba Exactly! This is at least how I understand the comments by soakley and Zahava Kor. And additionally that I have a large sample size what Rose Hartman interferes from the figure.

Comment: I think you are over-thinking this. Edit your question to clarify these issue ASAP. Some of the answers (e.g. soakley's) seem to be applicable to your actual situation - even if you are not satisfied with these approaches, they do attempt to address your real issue. I would go with your bullet point #1 and edit the question to clarify it as much as possible which IMHO requires shortening it a lot: remove the code, remove the figure, state very briefly what's going on. You can have a little note in the end mentioning why some of the comments talk about n=1000.

Comment: @amoeba You are absolutely right, I am completely over-thinking this. I will remove all the confusing additions and provide a link to the history for reference. Should I keep the part about why I am not satisfied with the existing answers?

Comment: Yes, this is an important part.